# How to append custom message to exception (in overrided methods which CANT throw exception)?

Tags: java, exception, throw

I know I can always catch exception in `try/catch` block and throw `Exception (message, e)` like this

```
    try {
        //...my code throwing some exception
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new Exception("Error details: bla bla", e);
    }
```

Easy. But it doesnt work in overriden methods, because they cant throw any exception with super method doesnt throw.

So, what are my options now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always opt for **unchecked** exceptions, that is sub-classes of `RuntimeException` class. These exceptions along with the sub-classes of `Error` are exempt from compile time checking.

Here `Parent` is defining `throwException()` method that does not have `throws` clause and the `Child` class overrides it but throws a new `RuntimeException` from the `catch` block.

```
class Parent{
    public void throwException(){
        System.out.println("Didn't throw");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void throwException(){
        try{
            throw new ArithmeticException("Some arithmetic fail");
        }catch(ArithmeticException ae){
            throw new RuntimeException(ae.getMessage(), ae);
        }
    }
}
```